# cp'd a file over another file with same name

Tags: cp

I just issued:

```
cp -r Photos ../
```

to another directory that had folder with the same name. I'm still in the terminal, but wanted to know if I could undo this somehow?

Comment: it was a cp -r Photos ../

Comment: unless you have some kind of version control already installed in your system, you have lost the folder and it's contents that you have replaced. You could use some kind of file recovery tool to acquire them back. That's the only ray of hope i see in this dark room.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is **NO**. I am sorry for disappointing you but Linux works on a principal `where something is gone then it's just simply gone`. That's the reason even `rm` doesn't throw files into trash. There is an alternative filesystem which is being developed to solve these kind of issues which is [copyfs](http://boklm.eu/copyfs/).

The other way is to use any version control system(Like `git`) so that you can fetch any previous versions of your files.

Comment: @Brian : Also let me know which file system are you using? So that I can suggest some recovery tools which comes without warranty :/ but you can try them

Comment: I'm using Mac OS, in Terminal.

Comment: @Brian I mean the file system. You can use `diskutil` to get the information.

Comment: Looks like a Hierarchical system

Comment: @Brian : As @rudimeier said you can try your luck with `TestDisk`.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned your action can't be un-done. But you can try to recover lost files from the file system, for example using  TestDisk or PhotoRec:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

To increase the chances that you will find some of your lost files again you should umount the relevant file system as quick as possible. Or shutdown your system and use a Rescue-CD:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd